# Create a list in microsoft word then change the color for one specific element in the list but even next element will have the number colored

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I create a list in word 2007 but I think I have had the same problem in 2013. I have

1 Some text

2 some text

3 some text

-make this one blue 4  some text

5 write some stuff - change this away from blue back to normal

(hit enter to make another element)

6 the text is not blue but the number 6 is blue and this would continue for 7,8 etc..

Why does the number in the list stay blue .

One quick fix is too use the format painter to fix erros likes this but I would like something better,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If paragraph marks aren't visible in Word, make them visible by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. You should see that the paragraph mark (¶) at the end of list item 4 and all the following list items is blue, like this:

[image: List with paragraph marks visible]

The color information for bullets/numbers is carried on the paragraph mark. So even if you reset the font color for the text in the new paragraph, unless you also reset it for the ¶, you'll propagate the bullet/number color to the next list item when you when you insert a new paragraph break.

To fix, if you don't have other character formatting applied in item 6 and following, you can select all those items (be sure to get the ¶ at the end of the last item), and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to clear all formatting. (Alternatively, you can select just the ¶ at the end of each item individually, and clear the formatting from it.) Then, any items that you add to the end of the list should have a non-colored number.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for the answer. Just tried it out